# YII 2.0 move data to another table using dropDownList

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm developing an Employee Page on `Yii 2`, but I have question.

I want to move the Prospective Employee to Employee Table when I changed the status from `Pending` to `Approved`

Here's some of my code:

```
[
  'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
  'attribute'=>'Stat',
  'width'=>'15%',
  'value'=>function($model){
      return (@$model->Stat=='0'?'Pending':'Approved');},
  'filter'=>['Pending','Diterima'],
  'label' => 'Status',
  'refreshGrid'=>true,
  'editableOptions'=> [
      'format' => Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,

      'asPopover' => true,
      'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
      'data'=>['0'=>'Pending', '1'=>'Approved'],
      'options' => ['class'=>'form-control'],
]
```

And here is the output from the generated code:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: can you show some controller code. ?? 
what you get by doing var_dump($_POST); in your controller ?

Comment: i haven't creating var_dump($_POST); yet,In index.php,when i change Pending into Approved,it only change in the database,

Comment: Means when you change Pending to Approved, the status is changes but employees are not inserted in table right ??

Comment: yes,i'm using 2 table,prospective and employee

Comment: You have to use  kartik\grid\EditableColumn with ActiveDataProvider based on db\Query

This might be helful.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514598/how-to-implement-correctly-kartik-grid-editablecolumn-with-activedataprovider-ba?rq=1

Comment: thank you,i solved the problem using the link above

Comment: Wow.. Great... enjoy :)